# element.scrollTo() function works in chrome and not in Edge

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

window.scrollTo() function belongs to window object. But when I tried to use like element.scrollTo(), it works in Chrome and throws error in Edge. I feel it should not work in both the browsers.

Does this mean Chrome has implemented it for elements in WebKit?
How can I see the source code for this function in Chrome WebKit?